# Do Japanese residents need a visa for South Korea?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, south-korea, filipino-citizens

My husband and I live in Japan and we're planning to travel to South Korea this June. We both hold a Philippine passport with a long-term resident Japanese visa. Do we still have to apply for a visa at the immigration or can we just do it online?

Comment: Could you clarify, please, whether you have Residence Card, or the special [Long Term Resident Visa](http://www.japanvisa.com/visas/long-term-resident), or both, as those with a Residence Card do not need a visa to visit Korea, according to Timatic.

Comment: @Dorothy Wrong, Japanese residency is not included

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=kr&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Philippines with a visa
>   issued by Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Cyprus, Czech
>   Rep., Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece,
>   Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New
>   Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia,
>   Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom if
>   in transit through Korea (Rep.) [for max 30 days].

Japan is not in the list. So unfortunately, you **do** need a visa

Comment: And in any case, the exception only applies "if in transit".

Comment: @fkraiem Which means not flying directly to the country you came directly from. They're flying the same route in both directions (I assume)

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say; it seems clear to me that they're flying from Japan to SK, and then back to Japan. That's not "transit", so the exception wouldn't apply even if Japan were in the list.